# How to get id of all the followers in socialengine using socialengine API or by anyother method?

Tags: api, curl, socialengine

I am using curl to get the list but it is showing an error 403 api key not found.

curl http://site.api.socialengine.com/member/1/followers?member_id=1&items_per_page=20&offset=1

Comment: I have gone through the API documentation of SocialEngine but I am confused where to place the api_key? whether I should put it in the url or define somewhere and use it?

Comment: You have to add api_key and other prams  in url such as get param

Comment: Since I am new to this can you provide me an example of how the URL should look like ?

Comment: Some thing like this curl https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&client_id=YOUR_API_KEY&client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
curl http://site.api.socialengine.com/member/1/followers?api_key={{api_key}}&member_id=1&items_per_page=20&offset=1
```

Where {{api_key}} is you api_key. You will set it. Read in documentation http://www.socialengine.com/support/cloud/api-doc#api-access